# Xcode Hangs at Startup

Tags: xcode, performance

Xcode fails to open on my machine - OS X 10.8.2. It opens the main screen and just hangs there with the spinner spinning becoming unresponsive. If I double click a project, it just hangs sating it is loading.

I tried:

1. Uninstalling and re-installing;
2. Removing my project tree;
3. Deleting some recommended preferences, most of which did not actually exist on my machine to begin with.

Things of note:

1. This is a new computer. The first time I ran Xcode, it opened fine, though I didn't try using it. The problem appeared when I first opened an existing project.
2. I created a new user on the machine. When that user is logged on Xcode loads successfully. Apparently it is a user settings issue.

Comment: You need to unhidden files first then try this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473231/xcode-5-crashes-on-new-project-creation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No need to reinstall Xcode.

Based on this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3830815

1. I deleted all Xcode related "Unsaved Docs" docs found via the Finder search;
2. I removed the `~/Library/Developer` folder;
3. Emptied the trash.

This worked for me.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/xcode ` worked for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: *warning* that this will remove all of your simulators and you will have to redownload all of them again if you clear `~/Library/Developer` folder

Comment: Caveat: This is a pretty old q+a by now.

Comment: This is the goddamn solution.

Comment: WARNING: `~/Library/Developer` contains your code snippets, color themes, custom key bindings and other user preferences. Instead of completely removing the folder, I recommend moving it to another location.

Comment: This does not work for me. Am using Xcode12.3

Answer (score 41):

Removing the `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState/`directory might help as well.

Comment: This does not work with xcode 7+. See @adi-shavit answer.

Comment: This does not work for me on Xcode 12.3

Comment: Works for me perfectly, nothing other solutions don't work

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem where xcode was hanging on opening one particular project.  I wanted a very precise fix without having to remove all the settings. I deleted `proj.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/<user>.userdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` from the *.xcodeproj* folder and that solved the problem.

So if you are having Xcode hang while attempting to open one particular project, this is the file that you need to delete.

Comment: had also to `rm -rf` all `proj.xc*/xcuserdata`s, then it worked. Xcode 13.1, Capacitor project, YMMV & be careful with `rm -rf`!

Answer (score 3):

A slightly improved answer:

I didn't need to reinstall Xcode at all, just remove the 'unsaved documents':

Search in `~/Library` for Xcode (by name)
(to search, you go to this folder, enter Xcode, with the drop down choose "by name", and then click the "Library
delete anything matching in `~/Library/Caches` or "`~/Library/Autosave Information`" or that looks like it might be an unsaved documents

Answer (score 2):

My problem was due to iCloud.
All my projects were inside documents folder which is iCloud folder.
Because iCloud settings in my MacBook was with the optimize option, the content of files weren’t allocated locally in the hard drive but remotely in iCloud. That was the cause for unresponsiveness of Xcode when loading the project or even starting new one.
I moved all the projects to local folder in hard disk not included as a backup for iCloud and it solved the problem.

Comment: If you need to back up your project, try Git. ;)

Comment: All projects were also with git.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the latest file (GPUToolsAgent.sock ) in that Xcode directory solved it.

```
Eds-MBP-3:echo ed$ ls -artl ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 ed  staff   64 Apr  2  2018 DocumentationCache
drwxr-xr-x   5 ed  staff  160 Feb 28 13:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  17 ed  staff  544 Apr 19 20:39 iOS Device Logs
drwxr-xr-x   7 ed  staff  224 Apr 29 12:18 DerivedData
drwxr-xr-x   5 ed  staff  160 Apr 29 12:40 UserData
srwxr-xr-x   1 ed  staff    0 Apr 29 13:56 GPUToolsAgent.sock
drwxr-xr-x   7 ed  staff  224 Apr 29 13:56 .
Eds-MBP-3:echo ed$ rm -f ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/GPUToolsAgent.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case source control was enabled and that's causing this issue

preferences > Source Control > uncheck Enable source control

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Alok it was driving me mad. All projects except one were loading when I upgraded to Xcode 15. Turning Source Control off got the other one working too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions on here and none of them worked. However, I managed to fix this issue and here is what worked for me: If you're on an apple OS and have iCloud sync enabled on your desktop/documents/any folder where you're loading Xcode from, the iCloud sync could be causing this issue.

I installed a fresh copy of my RN native on a folder not synced by iCloud and subsequently the issue was resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to delete Unsaved Docs related to Xcode, so I resorted to wiping out the whole hard drive after backing up my projects to Bitbucket. It worked, but it obviously took a while. If you can figure out how to delete unsaved files related to Xcode, I'd recommend doing that first. If you can't figure out how to do that like me, or it doesn't work, wiping out your hard drive should work.

This problem was intolerable. It took away my ability to do my job so I needed to fix it and I knew this method would work.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me when I updated an **XCode Source Editor Extension**.

**Deleting that extension app** from the `Applications` directory allowed XCode to start normally again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to delete:

```
~/Library/Developer/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
~/Library/Developer/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
~/workspace/MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
```

and once it helped. But another time it didn't help, so I also tried to reinstall Xcode, which also didn't help.

It turned out that the problem was that I was installing the app via WiFi or Bluetooth. When I connected my device via cable, the Xcode popped up to life and the "loading forever" stopped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open another project if you have, and then open your current project

---

Or creating a new Swift file, then open it.
Then go back to open your current project.
That may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Xcode 13.2.1 on macOS Monterey, Xcode had been hanging on startup, unrelated to any project, and none of the other answers helped.

I ended up resolving the problem by removing all Xcode Source Editor extensions: Go to **System Preferences** > **Extensions** > **Xcode Source Editor**, then uncheck any extensions that you may have installed.